# How to create our own component which can be resizable using AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

Using Flash CS5 and AS3, I have developed my own custom component which extends `UIComponent`.
I tried `super.setSize(w,h)`, `draw()`, `scaleX`, `scaleY`. But unable to figure out how to resize the component. Please help if anybody knows the solution.

Comment: could you please post your code?

Comment: @www0z0k - Thanks. As per your request of posting a code, i was going through code and i got the solution. Thanks again. I can post the code if anybody needs.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround of a component is

1. When a component is instantiated, one empty movieclip is addched to 
   the stage
2. Needed assets are added to that movieclip thereafter
3. Unlike movieclip, component won't scale entirely only the border asset/movieclip is tend to scale alone
4. If you want to resize the entire component like a movieclip you could resize all of it's children individually(may be in a for loop). The below code may helps you

   ```
    for(var i:int = 0; i < myComp.numChildren;i++){
       myComp.scaleX = 1.5;
    }
   ```